# PrimeFaces and browser compatibility

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Trying to get my head wrapped around PrimeFaces and JSF in general. How does PrimeFaces handle browser quirks/compatibility? Does the client-side code it generates contain all the necessary code to render in PF's supported browsers, or do I (the PF developer) need to add any client-side code (HTML/CSS/JS) needed to render the PF component correctly in different browsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As to JS, PrimeFaces delegates the browser-sensitive JS jobs to the bundled [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library. As to CSS, everything is done by the bundled [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library. As of now, jQuery and jQuery UI are very mature and supports a wide range of browsers, including IE6.
As to HTML, JSF should generate by specification XHTML 1.0 Transitional compliant HTML which is understood by every "modern" browser, including IE6, even when using HTML5 doctype.

You don't need to worry about this all, unless you're manually writing HTML/CSS/JS yourself.